# Draw different shape after line

Tags: ios, cgcontext

I am drawing line using Core Graphics.and i want to append different shape after(semi circle) completion of line .Again after semi circle ,i want to draw line.Here is code :

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect { // Drawing code
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0, 10);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 100, 10.0);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blueColor].CGColor);
    CGRect rectangle = CGRectMake(0,75,100,30);
    CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, rectangle);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
```

Please help me. Thanking you. Hint will also be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path to be drawn can be built up from many different parts, currently you move to the start point and draw a single line with `CGContextAddLineToPoint` but you can add more lines with the same function and add different lines like arcs with `CGContextAddArcToPoint` (there are several other options described in the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/CGContext.pdf)).

Comment: superb Mr Wain (Dark Night :D)...